# How to show image in TableViewCell from Firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a menu page in my app and for further when I will need make changes in pictures of my menu I want to know how to do it by firebase.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Please [edit] your question and replace the images with your actual code, as text, copied and pasted into the question. Pictures can't be searched or referenced and they are much harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the image type inside your string array and you should be good. Check the type of image you use if it is jpeg then it will be "1.jpg" and so on.

```
var imagesForMenu: [String] = ["1.png", "2.png"]
```